# Twistd Plugin not found after Debian upgrade

Tags: debian, twisted, twistd

After I upgraded from debian jessie to stretch, twistd does not find my plugin anymore. I could not find what's wrong. I guess I need to specify some path now which wasn't neccessary before or similar.

I get the error `/usr/bin/twistd: Unknown command: otfbot` and in the list of Commands, the two commands of the software are not listed anymore. The directory structure of the plugins for twisted is

```
twisted/plugins/genconfig_plugin.py
twisted/plugins/otfbot_plugin.py
```

And both instantiate a ServiceMaker.

Comment: How was your software installed?  What is the absolute path to the `twisted/plugins/` directory you reference?

Comment: twistd is installed globally as debian package and the plugin path is relative to the program folder. So I start it like ``cd /path/to/program;/usr/bin/twistd -n otfbot``. This worked with debian jessie's twistd version and does not work with stretch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twisted 16.4 removed the feature of `twistd` (and `trial` and all other Twisted command line scripts) which caused it to add the current working directory to `sys.path`.  If you were relying on your working directory to allow your code to be found when using a version of Twisted older than 16.4 (Debian Jessie includes 14.0.2) and you've upgraded to version 16.4 or newer (Debian Stretch includes 16.6.0) , you must now explicitly add the desired directories to the import path yourself, perhaps by setting up a virtualenv or by setting `PYTHONPATH` directly.

This was an accidental change and is not documented in the release notes (despite the clear, confusing user-facing consequences).

For more details, you can read this mailing list thread:

```
http://twistedmatrix.com/pipermail/twisted-python/2016-September/030780.html
```